# Issue with font-face css custom font

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

I have issue to get a `@font-face` css custom URL working for my wordpress theme. This is my setting:

[image: As you can see in the attached screenshot]

Did I do correct if yes why the font doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

If your site runs on HTTPS you must make sure the font does too. Otherwise it will be considered a security risk and then blocked (see the developer console (press F12) in your browser for such a message).

Comment: Then please add more information to the original question. Do you have a live link? Sample code etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the head section of web page

```
<link href="http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/73e731edac53f3db38b78336dff84fb2?family=Graphik+Web+Extralight" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

or, Using @import CSS directive, put the following line in add to your css file

```
@import url(http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/73e731edac53f3db38b78336dff84fb2?family=Graphik+Web+Extralight);
```

and write this font wherever you need it.

```
font-family: "Graphik Web Extralight";
```